# Google App Engine Managed VM won't deploy

Tags: google-app-engine

Everything was fine until this morning when the app stopped responding. I redeploy when this happens, but today, when I tried to redeploy it just said "Not enough VMs ready (0/1, 1 still deploying)." It said that all day.

I thought maybe the hard drive was over capacity, so I removed vm_settings and added a resources section to double the hard drive.

I deployed with appcfg.py with the static backend YAML looking like

```
application: happycyborg1
module: static-backend
version: 2  # not used with gcloud
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
vm: true
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 7.5
  disk_size_gb: 20
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: numpy
  version: "1.6.1"
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: live.APP
```

But I still get the same thing "Not enough VMs ready (0/1, 1 still deploying)."

If I try to deploy using `gcloud preview app deploy ./app.yaml ./static_backend.yaml` (removing "version 2" because that gave me an error) it still says "Not enough VMs ready (0/1, 1 still deploying)."

This was all working fine until about 16 hours ago. Now the whole app is down.

Comment: This can happen for a variety of reasons but it usually means the app is failing to start for some reason. Have you checked the logs? If you look in the console you should see some dropdown menus and maybe spot some errors in one of them. Also, if you don't get this figured out soon try dropping by https://gcp-slack.appspot.com/ during PST business hours and we can dig into details.

Comment: You might also want to double check you create new compute instances (to check you aren't over your VM quota). If so, maybe the solutions is to delete one of your versions.

Comment: Nothing in the log, other than HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable. The quotas all look fine. I only have one version.

Comment: Well, it started working on its own this morning. I did a dozen things yesterday without success. Maybe one of those things I did required a rotation of the earth to take effect.

Comment: :-\ Sorry to hear that, possible there's transient issues with your app but just as likely it was a transient bug with MVM. It's still a beta product as a lot of issues are still getting smoothed out, so sorry for inconvenience. Hope it doesn't happen again! I was going to mention one last debugging step you could have taken (for posterity) is to ssh to the VM and attach to the docker container and make sure everything is running as expected.